# typescript and react: redefine types for library

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to migrate from JSX to TSX and running into the following issue:

- I am using a third-party library (`React-Filepond`)
- The library accepts several types of props
- The types for this library are written by a person not related to the original library (`@types/react-filepond`), and these types only cover some of accepted props.

Example:

```
<FilePond
  server={{
      revert: () => this.props.updateUrl(this.state.oldImageUrl)
  }}
/>
```

this results in a type error, because the types for `server` prop are defined as:

```
interface FilePondServerConfigProps {
    server?: string | {
        revert: string | ServerUrl;
    }
}
```

and neither `string` nor `ServerUrl` are relevant to my case.

So the question is, how do I work around this, somehow redefine my types without issuing a PR to the types repo and waiting for it to be approved?

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is, how do I work around this, somehow redefine my types without issuing a PR to the types repo and waiting for it to be approved?

Definitely send the PR.

## Quick Fix

Use `patch-package` to patch it locally: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package